# Worksheet keeps on loading after refresh in Demantra

Tags: oracle, database-design

Oracle has suggested doing a data refresh to check on the issue of “Unable to save the data” which we are facing in the DEV instance. We thought the issue is due to the Demantra web generic patch which we had applied in the DEV instance for testing purposes.

After Prod data refresh When I tried to save the data in the worksheet and was still unable to save the data and it keeps on running.

Can be there any other issue in the Demantra DEV environment which is causing this issue as we are clear now the issue is not due to the web generic patch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: worksheet keeps on loading and does not open, this is the main problem and we don't know what's causing it .

Comment: Sorry but I doubt anyone in this channel knows anything about demantra or even what it is or does. From what I understand, it is some business application solution purchased by Oracle. Your best bet is just to contact oracle support. This channel is a generic channel for Database Administrators (not specific to Oracle)